# AngularJS, Loading spinner directive with transclude?

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive, angularjs-ng-transclude

I want to make a directive with shows a spinner when $http request is executing.

I thought this would be working (e.g. load users):

Main Controller

```
app.controller('UserListController', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.users = [];
    $scope.loading = true;

    $http.get('/users').then(function(response) {
        $scope.users = response.data;
    }).finally(function() { $scope.loading = false; });

});
```

Template using the directive

```
<div request-loading="loading">
    <ul>
       <li ng-repeat="user in users">{{ user.name }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

request-loading-directive.js

```
app.directive('requestLoading', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
           requestLoading: '='
        },

        transclude: true, // I think this is not Ok

        templateUrl: 'request-loading-directive.html'
    };
});
```

request-loading-template.html

```
<div ng-show="requestLoading" class="super-cool-spinner">
    Loading text with the spinner...
</div>

// This is what is not working
// I thought the content of the users (ul and li) would be render in this div
// when the request is Ok.
<div ng-transclude ng-show="! requestLoading"></div>
```

Any help would be nice!
Thx.

Comment: have you tried to put `$scope.loading = false;` at the end of the `.then()` block ?

Comment: Working fine here: http://plnkr.co/edit/seWdgwXi9KOLEY2hclPe?p=preview. I replaced the http promise by a timeout promise to test it, but it shouldn't change anything. Please create a plunkr reproducing the problem. Check your console for errors.

Comment: I don't understand what is not working correctly ? here is a fork of your [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nzU1Nj9TlfAZy8niT6mF?p=preview) with an $http call. The loader seems to work correctly.

Comment: Well, magic: it is working now. I check and I forgot "ng-show" of the ng-transclude. Sorry about that!